# Can .htaccess urls be redirected like this?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have my .htaccess set up and it is working great for links like:

```
http://localhost:8888/z-jquery/view
http://localhost:8888/z-jquery/search
```

so it is removing .php extension and also redirecting if they are typed in manually which is perfect but I also need my other urls like:

```
http://localhost:8888/z-jquery/edit?client=dane+kasbo
```

to be like this if possible:

```
http://localhost:8888/z-jquery/dane+kasbo
```

this is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /z-jquery/

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Note: I have searched a lot of .htaccess questions here but none work for me, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /z-jquery/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /edit(?:\.php)?\?client=([^&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R,L,NE]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ edit.php?client=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help friend but this does not seem to work for me, I get this url which ofcourse does not work: http://localhost:8888/z-jquery/lionel+messi?client=lionel+messi this is what it redirects me to, maybe I should be make my edit link differently if so please do help thanks again for helping out.

Comment: it is located inside the htdocs/z-jquery/ folder and the url is like this: <a href="edit?client=<?php echo urlencode($clients['client_name']); ?>"><?php echo $status; ?></a> I have also tried adding the .php after the edit but that didnt work either

Comment: the one I pasted above thats what it redirected me too.  
Usually without the .htaccess file the link would of been edit.php?client=lionel+messi

Comment: but when I try to access this link now before it was working now it does not work anymore http://localhost:8888/z-jquery/view

it gives me a 404 error and says: The requested URL /z-query/v.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Perfect Now! thank you very much friend and if you could point me in the right direction for learning more about .htaccess would appreciate it a lot I have tried many sites but none really have worked out well or maybe a book or something, thanks again